userMethod.value is taking null value even though inside if log is logging correct value
 override fun detectMethod(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        val userMethod = MutableLiveData<String>()
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener {
            val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
            if (currentUser!!.providerData.size > 0) {
                Log.d("inside if",currentUser.providerData[currentUser.providerData.size - 1].providerId)
                userMethod.value =
                    currentUser.providerData[currentUser.providerData.size - 1].providerId
            }
        }
        Log.d("repository", userMethod.value.toString())
        return userMethod
    }

I need value currentUser.providerData[currentUser.providerData.size - 1].providerId  in userMethod.value

If you want to read the value that exists inside a LiveData object, you should not check the value field that exists inside the object, you have to observe the changes, otherwise, the value will always be null. So please check the official documentation regarding how to start observing a LiveData object. In code, it will be as simple as:
val observer = Observer<String> { providerId ->
    Log.d("TAG", providerId)
}
userMethod.observe(this, observer)

But since you're using Kotlin, I recommend a more elegant way to achieve the same thing. Nowadays, it's best to use Kotlin Coroutine and Asynchronous Flow. So I think that this resource will help. Here is the corresponding repo.

Hey Lakshay. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?
